# I need help on converting algorithm to java

Tags: java, algorithm

```
Algorithm fibIterative(integer num)
{
 set i to 1
 set j to 0
 for (k = 1 to num) {
 set j = i + j
 set i = j - i
  }
 return j
}
```

I know my for loop is wrong but i don't know how to make it right.
Hope someone can help me with it. Thanks in advance

```
    for (int k = 1; k < num; k++)
    {
        int j = i + j;
        int i = j - 1;
    }
```

Comment: `for (k = 1 to num) {` - Ask yourself, where does `k` start and where does it end?

Comment: Oh yeah, it should be **for (int k =1; k < num; k++)**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class fibIterative {

  public int AfibIterative (int num)
  {
    int i = 1;
    int j = 0;

    for (int k = 1; k < num; k++)
    {
         j = i + j;
         i = j - 1;
    }
    return j;   
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you declare variables inside a loop in java, they're gone by the time the iteration is over.

```
public int fibIterative(int num) {
    int i = 1;
    int j = 0;

    for (int k = num; k <= num; k++) {
        j = i + j;
        i = j - 1;
    }

    return j;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The converted code would be:

```
public int fibInteractive(int num) {
    int i = 1;
    int j = 0;

    for (int k = 1; k <= num; k++) {
        j = i + j;
        i = j - 1;
    }
    return j;
}
```

However, I don't think that this code is going to work the way you intend. Passing in 4 as an argument still yielded 1 as the returned value, because of the way that `i` is reset in each iteration:

> ```
> // Iteration #1
> j = 1 + 0
> i = 1 - 1
> // j's value at this point is 1. i's value is 0.
>
> // Iteration #2
> j = 0 + 1
> i = 1 - 1
> // j's value at this point is 1. i's value is 0.
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Your full Java program should look like this:

```
public class algorithm {

    public static void main(String []args) {
        int ans = fibIterative(23);
        System.out.println(ans);
    }

    static int fibIterative(int num) {
        int i = 1,j = 0,k;
        for(k = 1;k <= num; k++) {
            j = i + j;
            i = j - i;
        }
        return j;
    }
}
```